# JS / d3.js - Removing/merging duplicate links in d3.js node graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js

Good day!

I am a beginner in js/d3.js and I am currently working on a small project.. here are my previous questions:

- [D3.js: Dynamically generate source and target based on identical json values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41138515/d3-js-dynamically-generate-source-and-target-based-on-identical-json-values)
- [JS / d3.js: Steps to Highlighting of adjacent links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244508/js-d3-js-steps-to-highlighting-of-adjacent-links)

My project aims to dynamically create source and target pairs based on user inputs. However, in doing so, I have several nodes with duplicated links. Upon further inspection, I realised that it may be due to duplicated Source/Target elements in the created array. Here is an excerpt of what happened inside the 'links' array:

```
//Source and target are unique identifiers of each datastruct
source: S001A, target: S002A
source: S001A, target: S003A
source: S001A, target: S004A       
source: S002A, target: S001A //Duplicate
source: S002A, target: S005A
source: S003A, target: S001A //Duplicate
source: S003A, target: S006A
source: S004A, target: S001A //Duplicate
                  ...
```

This is due to my raw data having a nested array for "Friends", here is a sample entry in the dataset:

```
{
   "NRIC": "S001A",
   "name": "Benjamin",
   "blk": 123,
   "estate": "Woodlands",
   "street": "Woodlands Street 12",
   "unitNo": "01-23",
   "postal": 123123,
   "school": "Nanyang Technological University",
   "Friends": //Nested array..
   [
      "S002A",
      "S003A",
      "S004A",
   ]
}
```

Here is the for-loop that I am using to create the source-target arrays for the nested data:

```
graphData.forEach(function(gdata,index)
{
    for (i = 0; i < gdata.Friends.length; i++)
    {
        links.push({
            source: gdata.NRIC,
            target: gdata.Friends[i]
        });     
    }
});
```

This for loop will understandably cause duplicates down the line as friends are mutually inclusive of each other. (i.e. S001A is friends with S002A, S003A and S004A. S002A will have S001A inside his 'Friends' array as well).

While I thought of only using the source/target pairs where source === this.id, but I am afraid that I may then omit some pairs and that will affect the integrity of the data..

Is there a way whereby I can iterate through and remove pairings from the array? Either by amending the current for-loop, or to do post-processing of the data..

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago, check if the solution works in your case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40167473/5768908

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Although the sort function didn't work in my case as I am comparing alphanumeric values, I did manage to do it in a roundabout manner, although I know that this method will result in performance issues.. I will post my solution below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Gerardo Furtado for the help!

I slightly tweaked the solution as I require sorting of alphanumeric values, but here is my working answer:

```
graphData.forEach(function(gdata,index)
{
    for (i = 0; i < gdata.Friends.length; i++)
    {
        links.push({
            source: gdata.NRIC,
            target: gdata.Friends[i]
        });     
    }
});

links.forEach(function(d) {
    var sourceTemp = d.source, targetTemp = d.target;
    if (d.source > d.target)
    {
        d.source = targetTemp;
        d.target = sourceTemp;
    }
});

//links.sort(); doesn't work as item to be sorted may be alphanmueric :(
var linkslength = links.length;

links.forEach(function(d,i)
{
    var curSrc = d.source, curTgt = d.target;
    for(var j = i+1; j < linkslength; j++)
    {
        if (links[j].source === curSrc && links[j].target === curTgt)
        {
            links.splice(j,1);
            linkslength -= 1;
        }
    }
});
```

I know that this is a very unoptimized version, is there any way to optimize the number of times I have to loop? Also, I am worried that the links.length does not auto-update itself after each splice, hence I stored it into a variable and manually decreased it after each splice.

Thank you Gerardo Furtado and SO for the help! Cheers:)

Comment: Thank you for your help yet again! :)