# Dynamic assignment of groups to source/target pairings

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Following up on my previous question:

[JS / d3.js - Removing/merging duplicate links in d3.js node graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438178/js-d3-js-removing-merging-duplicate-links-in-d3-js-node-graph)

I would like to ask if there is a way to dynamically assign groups to nodes that are joined together by edges.

This is because I would like to colour the nodes in each cluster with the same colour, and the source/target data is provided by an external dataset.

Here is a sample source/target data:

```
source: S001A, target: S002A
source: S001A, target: S003A
source: S001A, target: S004A       
source: S002A, target: S005A
source: S003A, target: S006A
```

and here is my node creation portion of the code:

```
node = node
    .data(nodeD)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 6)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return colors(/*Code here..*/); }) 
    .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));
```

And my nodeD data structure contains my node data, a sample is shown below:

```
{
   "NRIC": "S001A",
   "name": "Benjamin",
   "blk": 123,
   "estate": "Woods",
   "street": "Woods Street 80",
   "unitNo": "12-98",
   "postal": 123456,
   "school": "Nanyang Technological University",
   "Friends": [
      "S002A",
      "S003A",
      "S004A",
   ]
}
```

Is there a way to colour nodes that are in the same 'group', or cluster, of nodes by source/target data? Or do I need to introduce a new attribute in my node's data structure to group them together?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by *cluster* you mean nodes that are linked together, without any link to another *cluster*.

Thus, if that's the case, in the following force chart we have 2 clusters:

```js
var width = 300;
 var height = 200;
 var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", width)
     .attr("height", height);

 var nodes = [{
     "id": "foo"
 }, {
     "id": "bar"
 }, {
     "id": "baz"
 }, {
     "id": "foobar"
 }, {
     "id": "foobaz"
 }, {
     "id": "barbar"
 }, {
     "id": "barbaz"
 }];

 var edges = [{
     "source": 0,
     "target": 1
 }, {
     "source": 0,
     "target": 2
 }, {
     "source": 0,
     "target": 3
 }, {
     "source": 1,
     "target": 3
 }, {
     "source": 4,
     "target": 5
 }, {
     "source": 4,
     "target": 6
 }, {
     "source": 5,
     "target": 6
 }];

 var force = d3.forceSimulation()
     .force("link", d3.forceLink()
         .id(function(d, i) {
             return i
         }))
     .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
     .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

 var myedges = svg.selectAll("line")
     .data(edges)
     .enter()
     .append("line")
     .style("stroke", "#ccc")
     .style("stroke-width", 1);

 var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

 var mynodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
     .data(nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("circle")
     .attr("r", 10)
     .style("fill", "#888")
     .call(d3.drag());

 force.nodes(nodes);
 force.force("link")
     .links(edges);

 force.on("tick", function() {
     myedges.attr("x1", function(d) {
             return d.source.x;
         })
         .attr("y1", function(d) {
             return d.source.y;
         })
         .attr("x2", function(d) {
             return d.target.x;
         })
         .attr("y2", function(d) {
             return d.target.y;
         })

     mynodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
             return d.x;
         })
         .attr("cy", function(d) {
             return d.y;
         });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

How to colour the nodes by their cluster? This is my solution:

First, sort your `edges` or `links` array, by source *and* target. Once it's sorted, you can use the following function:

```
 var cluster = [
     [edges[0].source, edges[0].target]
 ];


 var found;
 edges.forEach(d => {
     found = 0;
     for (var i = 0; i < cluster.length; i++) {
         if (cluster[i].indexOf(d.source) > -1 && cluster[i].indexOf(d.target) < 0) {
             cluster[i].push(d.target);
             found = 1;
         } else if (cluster[i].indexOf(d.target) > -1 && cluster[i].indexOf(d.source) < 0) {
             cluster[i].push(d.source);
             found = 1;
         } else if (cluster[i].indexOf(d.target) > -1 && cluster[i].indexOf(d.source) > -1) {
             found = 1;
         }
     }
     if (!found) {
         cluster.push([d.source, d.target])
     }
 });
```

It's not a beatiful function, I'm the first to agree: it has a global and definitely could be shortened. But here is what the function does:

After creating an array named `cluster` with the first pair of source and target as an (inner) array, the function checks for all other pairs. If either the source or the target is present, it pushes the new value to the inner array. If not, it creates a new array with the new values.

Then, you can colour your nodes by the index of the node in that `cluster` array:

```
.style("fill", function(d, i) {
    for (j = 0; j < cluster.length; j++) {
        if (cluster[j].indexOf(i) > -1) {
            return color(j)
        }
    }
})
```

Note that in this example the `edges` are specified by the index of the nodes array. In your case, you have strings.

All together, this is the demo:

```js
var width = 300;
     var height = 200;
     var svg = d3.select("body")
         .append("svg")
         .attr("width", width)
         .attr("height", height);

     var nodes = [{
         "id": "foo"
     }, {
         "id": "bar"
     }, {
         "id": "baz"
     }, {
         "id": "foobar"
     }, {
         "id": "foobaz"
     }, {
         "id": "barbar"
     }, {
         "id": "barbaz"
     }];

     var edges = [{
         "source": 0,
         "target": 1
     }, {
         "source": 0,
         "target": 2
     }, {
         "source": 0,
         "target": 3
     }, {
         "source": 1,
         "target": 3
     }, {
         "source": 4,
         "target": 5
     }, {
         "source": 4,
         "target": 6
     }, {
         "source": 5,
         "target": 6
     }];

     var cluster = [
         [edges[0].source, edges[0].target]
     ];


     var found;
     edges.forEach(d => {
         found = 0;
         for (var i = 0; i < cluster.length; i++) {
             if (cluster[i].indexOf(d.source) > -1 && cluster[i].indexOf(d.target) < 0) {
                 cluster[i].push(d.target);
                 found = 1;
             } else if (cluster[i].indexOf(d.target) > -1 && cluster[i].indexOf(d.source) < 0) {
                 cluster[i].push(d.source);
                 found = 1;
             } else if (cluster[i].indexOf(d.target) > -1 && cluster[i].indexOf(d.source) > -1) {
                 found = 1;
             }
         }
         if (!found) {
             cluster.push([d.source, d.target])
         }
     });

     var force = d3.forceSimulation()
         .force("link", d3.forceLink()
             .id(function(d, i) {
                 return i
             }))
         .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
         .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

     var myedges = svg.selectAll("line")
         .data(edges)
         .enter()
         .append("line")
         .style("stroke", "#ccc")
         .style("stroke-width", 1);

     var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

     var mynodes = svg.selectAll("circle")
         .data(nodes)
         .enter()
         .append("circle")
         .attr("r", 10)
         .style("fill", function(d, i) {
             for (j = 0; j < cluster.length; j++) {
                 if (cluster[j].indexOf(i) > -1) {
                     return color(j)
                 }
             }
         })
         .call(d3.drag());

     force.nodes(nodes);
     force.force("link")
         .links(edges);

     force.on("tick", function() { //update the position of lines
         myedges.attr("x1", function(d) {
                 return d.source.x;
             })
             .attr("y1", function(d) {
                 return d.source.y;
             })
             .attr("x2", function(d) {
                 return d.target.x;
             })
             .attr("y2", function(d) {
                 return d.target.y;
             })

         mynodes.attr("cx", function(d) {
                 return d.x;
             })
             .attr("cy", function(d) {
                 return d.y;
             });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```